# Dependencies of nuget package are not copied to output folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

Visual Studio 2019 16.10.0
.Net 5

I've made a nuget package for company internal use.
In this package, i references Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices which references many other packages:

[image: References of Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices]

When i now use this nuget package in another project, then only my assembly (and few others) are copied to output folder, but many of the referenced assemblies are missing, like:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets.dll
- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
- Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.*

In the project, that i've build, there is CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies=true.
What can i do, to copy the missing assemblies to output folder (without xcopy in PostBuild)?

Comment: the project that you're building in the example (that isn't including transitive dependencies in the output): is this a *library* project, or an *application* project?

Comment: The project, that builds to the output folder is a library project, but the project that creates the nuget package is an application project and includes the *.exe in the contentFiles folder of the nuget package.

Comment: what real issues do you have with that? Any runtime errors? Why it's bothering you?

Comment: The error message on starting the executable is: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.dll

Comment: Library projects do not fully explode transitive dependencies in terms.of build output. Try with an application build; that's when it becomes interesting.

Comment: @Marc Gravell thx for the hint. That helps me.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @Ryebread In the future, we will build only libraries as NuGet packages and create executables in the conrete customer project.

Comment: does anyone have an idea, on how to actually fix this as an application? Especially unit test projects need to stay a library project, but on the otherhand need transitive dependencies like configuration files or test data.