# NuGet package's dependent assemblies not being copied locally

Tags: dependencies, blazor, .net-6.0

I've created a new Blazor WASM project and added to it a NuGet package from my private internal feed (let's call it `Package1`). `Package1` in turn depends on the `Portable.BouncyCastle` package.

In my Blazor project, when I call methods from the `Package1` assembly, I'm getting an exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'BouncyCastle.Crypto, Version=1.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0e99375e54769942'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Why aren't `Package1`'s dependencies being copied locally when I build the project? As far as I can recall, this was never an issue in the old .NET Framework. Add a package to a dependent project, the package's dependencies come along with it.

I see there's a somewhat similar problem going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69134080), but unfortunately there's been no answer posted so far. There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15816769), but it's nine years old and is most certainly irrelevant by now.

My setup:

- `Blazor1`: .NET6 Blazor WASM
- `Package1`: .NET Standard 2.0

There's nothing in Visual Studio's NuGet Package Manager options that would address this, nor is there a modern equivalent to the old `CopyLocal` setting in the reference's properties sheet.

How can I get `Package1`'s dependencies copied locally without adding `Portable.BouncyCastle` to `Blazor1`?